# Not sure what to do - session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to install an Panel on my web hosting, I did install it correctly, but whenver I try to login to the panel I receive this Error:

session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active

I am not an PHP developer, or know anything about codes, I would be happy if I get great explanation

I am using 7.1 PHP version

Here is the LoginForm:

```
<?php

class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
public $username;
public $password;
public $rememberMe;

private $_identity;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('username, password', 'required'),
        array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'rememberMe'=>'Stay logged in',
        'username'=>'Username',
        'password'=>'Password',
    );
}

public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password','Invalid username, password, or verification code.');
    }
}

public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: <?php
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
?>

I think, you are not started session to regenerate session.. So add the above code top of all the php codes where ever you would like to use session.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, the panel was working good, but when I moved to a new host, this problem happened.

Comment: Okay, So can you look at your server error log ?

Answer (score 0):

**PHP SESSION NOT STARTED**

```
<?php
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) { 
session_start(); 
}
?>
```

Add the above code on all of your PHP pages.. it will automatically start session if session not started.